# String in a macro - how to pass it to a command defined in another command as a default optional argument?

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox, xstring

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,etoolbox}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\def\lists{%
    parts-a),
    items-1)
}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \StrCut{#1}{-}\csA\csB
    % the next line is the "crucial one"
    \expandafter\providecommand\csname my\csA\endcsname[1][\csB]{%
        \begin{enumerate}[##1]
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    }
}
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\lists}

\begin{document}
\myparts[i)]
\myparts
\end{document}
```

It produces

```
i) one
ii) two
1) one
1) two
```

How should I modify the "crucial line" so that it works as expected, i.e. produces

```
i) one
ii) two
a) one
b) two
```

?

As far as I understand I need to pass \csB "expanded". But I played with various edef's and expandafter's for a few hours, I am on the verge of madness, and I ran out of ideas.

(The above is a distilled minimal example - in reality it's a more useful code, but I think the above captures my problem well)

EDIT: siracusa's answer below seems to be working, unfortunately I don't know how to do a notch more difficult example with the following modification

```
\begin{enumerate}[##1]
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
The above list is of type \csB
```

As above it will print "The above list is of type 1)" all the time, and it's not clear to me how to modify siracusa's answer to correctly expand \csB which is in the definition of \myparts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to be what you want:

```
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \StrCut{#1}{-}\csA\csB
    % the next line is the "crucial one"
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\providecommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname my\csA\endcsname[1][\csB]}%
    \temp{%
        \begin{enumerate}[##1]
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    }
}
```

We first define a temporary command `\temp` that fully expands the `\providecommand` parameters, except for the `\providecommand` macro itself which is prevented by `\noexpand`. Then `\temp` is executed to actually perform the command definition.

---

Here's a new version wrt. the extended question:

```
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \StrCut{#1}{-}\csA\csB
    % the next line is the "crucial one"
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\providecommand\expandafter\noexpand\csname my\csA\endcsname[1][\csB]{%
        \noexpand\begin{enumerate}[####1]
            \noexpand\item one
            \noexpand\item two
        \noexpand\end{enumerate}
        The above list is of type \csB
    }%
    }\temp
}
```

The `\edef` now spans the whole defintion, not only the parameters. This makes it necessary to prefix all used commands that should not be expanded by `\noexpand`, though. Not sure if this is practical in your real code. The `xparse` version suggested by egreg is more flexible here.

Comment: Won't the `\edef` expand `\csname my\csA\endcsname`? If the command is not already defined, it'll be set to `\relax` so it won't expand further, but if it's already defined, it'll keep expanding.

Comment: @TH. This is intended, isn't it? The `\csA` is part of the name for the command, the `\csB` is the parameter. In the original definition, expansion of `\csA` was triggered by `\expandafter`.

Comment: `\newcommand\problem{
 \def\csA{foo}
 \def\csB{bar}
 \edef\temp{\noexpand\providecommand\csname my\csA\endcsname[1][\bar]}
 \temp{[##1]}
}` is a simplified version of `\do`. If you use `\problem` once, everything works. If you use `\problem` a second time, it fails with an error. The problem is expanding `\csname my\csA\endcsname` expands to `\myfoo` which then expands because the first execution of `\problem` defined it.

Comment: @siracusa I did some limited testing and so far it works ok. I have a question relevant to my real life code: could you modify the code so that after \end{enumerate} there is "The above list is of type \csB"? I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @TH. Ah, it's clear now what you mean. I modified the code above to fix that.

Comment: Many thanks. After your initial answer I figured the code for the extended version except for ####1, with stuff like \string#1 all over the place (which didn't work).  As for TH's obojection, I now understand what you mean - I actually didn't envounter it myself because I had  \expandafter\let\csname\csA\endcsname\@undefined in the original code before the edef, which  perhaps increases readability a little bit.

Comment: Btw, is there a documentation somewhere (presumably for `\edef`) which includes the tricks like  `####1` ?

Comment: It's explained in Knuth's The TeXbook; TeX by Topic certainly also mentions it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `\providecommand` for this. Moreover, redefining `\do` is quite dangerous, because several packages can use it. With `etoolbox` you have `\forcsvlist`, which accepts a different macro.

The main problem is passing `\csB` expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,etoolbox}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newcommand\lists{%
    parts-a),
    items-1)
}

\newcommand*{\mydo}[1]{%
    \StrCut{#1}{-}\csA\csB
    % build \newcommand one step at a time
    \toks0=\expandafter{\expandafter\newcommand\csname my\csA\endcsname}%
    \toks2=\expandafter{\csB}%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\the\toks0[1][\the\toks2]}\x{%
        \begin{enumerate}[##1]
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    }%
}
\expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\mydo\expandafter{\lists}

\begin{document}
\myparts[i)]
\myparts
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a different approach, based on `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\parselists}{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\makelist}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}{m}}{%
  \makelistsdo#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makelistsdo}{mm}{%
  \NewDocumentNamedCommand{my#1}{O{#2}}{%
        \begin{enumerate}[##1]
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \NewDocumentNamedCommand #1
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parselists{
  parts-a),
  items-1),
}

\begin{document}
\myparts[i)]
\myparts
\myitems[i)]
\myitems
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit to the question to make it a notch more difficult - would your approach solve also the new question? (I'm more interested in the etoolbox version because it looks more readable to my latex2e-trained eyes)   Also what's wrong with \providecommand? In my case the command will be both in a cls file and in a sty file, and sometimes I need to use only cls file without sty, or only sty file without cls, or both at the same time, so providecommand seemed natural